# In merge sort, what will be the time complexity if in each recursion, we break the array in two parts of size 1/4 and 3/4 respectively?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, recurrence-relation, divide-and-conquer, mergesort

Let's say number of elements are a power of 4. Now if we break the array in parts of 1/4 and 3/4, how do we calculate the time complexity in this case?

Comment: Is the 3:1 partitioning done recursively or only at the first level?

Comment: @RayButterworth it is portioned in 3:1 recursively

Comment: So the "*Let's say number of elements are a power of 4.* is irrelevant and confusing, since after the first level at most one of the partitions can be a power of 4.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c \in (0, \frac{1}{2}]$ be any constant. In your case $c = \frac{1}{4}$.

If, at a generic recursive call, you partition the $n$ elements in your input array into a subarray of size $cn$ and another of size $(1-c)n$ (floors and ceilings are omitted for simplicity here), you can describe the running time of mergesort with the following recurrence equation:

$$
T(n) = T(cn) + T((1-c)n) + O(n).
$$

The solution to this recurrence is $T(n)=O(n \log n)$.

To see this, consider the recursion tree.
If $n$ is the size of the original input, then the largest input size of a call at depth $d$ is at most $(1-c)^d n$. By solving $(1-c)^d n \ge 1$ for $d$, we see that there can be at most $\log_{1-c} \frac{1}{n} = \dfrac{\log \frac{1}{n}}{\log (1-c)} = \dfrac{\log n}{\log \frac{1}{1-c}}$ levels of recursion.

Notice now that the input sizes on each level of recursion cannot sum to more than $n$, therefore the overall time spent on each level is at most $O(n)$, and the running time of the algorithm is at most $O(n) \cdot \dfrac{\log n}{\log \frac{1}{1-c}} = O(n \log n)$.

Comment: Nice answer! For readability purposes, you should use `\dfrac` instead of `frac`.

Comment: I edited the answer to use `\dfrac`, thanks :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!